# Upgrading book module from v7 to v9 - no rows in book table

Tags: migrations, upgrading

I'm upgrading a site from v7 to v9. The entire site is composed of about 10,000 book pages. All the nodes migrate successfully, but the book tree has no contents and the table 'book' has zero rows. It appears the structure of the table in v9 is different than v7, so I cannot just export / import the contents to migrate the structure.

How can I migrate the book tree from v7 to v9?

Comment: Have you tried the migrate API? https://www.drupal.org/docs/core-modules-and-themes/core-modules/migrate-drupal-module